# how to extract Removable memory device in java

Tags: java

i want to make a program that can extract the data from a removable memory device

Comment: Good luck with that! Tell us how it goes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:

```
File file = new File("/path/to/removable/device", "path/to/file");

BufferedFileReader fileReader = new BufferedFileReader(new FileReader(file));

String line = fileReader.readLine();
```

But you're going to have to give us much more detail. What sort of data are you trying to retrieve from the removable memory device? Is it already mounted? Can it be mounted?